# php laravel the select could be a bug for hackers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I do this in a controller

```
$sources = array('' => 'Select Source') + Sources::lists('name', 'id');
```

where `Source` is a model.

Then in the view, I do this:

```
{{Form::select('source_id', $sources, '', $sources)}}
        <span>{{$errors->first('source_id')}}</span>
```

The result HTML is:

```
<select ="select="" source"="" dubizzle="Dubizzle" name="source_id">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Source</option>
    <option value="1">Dubizzle</option>
</select>
```

As you see the first option, which is `Select Source` has no value. Thus, when I submit the form **without choosen any source**, and validate the inputs like this:

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::All(), XMLDocument::$rules);
        if($validation->passes()){}else{
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
        }
```

I got error message that the `source_id` is required.

that works perfectly.

#### My problem

I inspect the HTML using Google Chrome F12 Developing Tool and I added a value to the `Select Source` option. then I submit the form and the validate didn't catch the error. That is because the `source_id` has a value.

The hacker can easily manipulate the HTML and my server and database will fall because this `source_id` is a foreign key and everything is connected to it.

How to save myself from that please?

#### Update 1

The rule for validate the `source_id` is:

```
'source_id' => 'required|integer',
```

Comment: So what rulesets have you applied to your source_id property in the validation

Comment: @MarkBaker I just updated the question including your request.

Comment: You can forge every form element, it your job to sanitize and validate the input.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
$sources = array('' => 'Select Source') + Sources::lists('name', 'id');
```

You may use:

```
$sources = array('Select Source') + Sources::lists('name', 'id');
```

So the first item will be:

```
<option value="0">Select Source</option>
```

Then in your rules just add `not_in:0`, for example:

```
'source_id' => 'required|integer|not_in:0'
```

It'll work because no element/record in you database is going to have an id of `0`. I do this always.

Comment: Look who's back :) now I am working on the other project. I will test your solution tonight, +1

Comment: Actually I'm also busy with a `Laravel` project and a `Laravel book` of mine so can't be here as often. All the best with your new project :-)

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha wow sounds great, all the best with your new book, I am gonna buy it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate that the selected source was a valid source. You can probably use the `exists` rule for this, or if that's a no go then simply create a custom rule. I'd say that the `exists` rule should fit the bill though.

Comment: What about in some cases - you need to not just check "exists" - but that it is a valid relationship or the foreign-id belongs to *that user*. I have this problem all the time. I'm using a custom ruleset that does a lookup to see if the relationship exists, and validate on that...?

Comment: I already gave you the rule I am using, could you add that `exists` validation to my rule?

Comment: `'source_id' => 'required|integer|exists',`